# matplotlib line plot dont show vertical lines in step function

Tags: matplotlib

I do have a plot that only consists of horizontal lines at certain values when I have a signal, otherwise none. So, I am looking for a way to plot this without the vertical lines. there may be gaps between the lines when there is no signal and I dont want the lines to connect nor do I want a line falling off to 0. Is there a way to plot this like that in matplotlib?

[image]

```
self.figure = plt.figure()
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
axes.plot(df.index, df["x1"], lw=1.0, c=self.getColour('g', i), ls=ls)
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: there are a few lines. not sure what else you could need

Comment: What happens is that we can not help but see what mistakes you have made or the things you have used.

Comment: For example, with the portion of code that I understand you are using pandas.

Answer (score 10):

The plot you are looking for is Matplotlib's `plt.hlines(y, xmin, xmax)`.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = range(1, 11)
xmin = range(10)
xmax = range(1, 11)
colors=['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange', 'purple', 
        'cyan', 'magenta', 'pink', 'black']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hlines(y, xmin, xmax, colors=colors)
plt.show()
```

Yields a plot like this:

[image: Matplotlib hlines plot]

See the [Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) for more details.

Comment: Great! A pandas tip for `DatetimeIndex` with `freq=None`: shift forward in time using `df.index[1:].append(df.index[-1:])`.